# Java Ant Performance when deleting directory

Tags: java, performance, ant

Hello fellow stackoverflowers,

Most Ant build files I've seen online involve a "clean" target that always removes a directory using deltree and recreates that directory, where all the binaries will be outputted to.  Is this a performance problem?  That is, a source file should only be compiled if it has been changed, but if the directory holding all the binaries is deleted after every build, then all files have to be recompiled on each build.  Is this what happens, and if so, am I wrong in saying that this could really hurt performance.

As a follow up question, is doing this absolutely necessary or highly recommended when using Ant?  My team happens to be using dropbox to sync to multiple machines, and we may not want this step to occur on every run.

Thanks for any input!

-alanhorizon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean is generally superfluous if you are adding or changing existing classes. `javac` checks the timestamp of`class` files to keep them up to date. 
It becomes essential if some classes have been deleted. If you don't clean up first, you end up with outdated `class` files sometimes causing dependency issues.
And no, performing a clean up is **not** a performance impact worth to mention compared to other tasks involved in the build/deployment process.

Comment: this is still a little confusing to me, perhaps I still don't fully understand how the build process on ant works.  performing a clean is just deleting all the binaries.  how would this not be a performance issue; wouldn't this force a re-compilation of all source?  and wouldn't that take a while, assuming it's a large project?

Comment: @Alan don't get me wrong here, deleting and recompiling has an impact. There is no magic there. But...1. in our current project - a java enterprise application, the compilation of the source files is responsible for ca. 10 to 20 % of the build time in a complete build. The rest is spent generating XML-bound classes, web service stubs, performing automated tests, auditing the code etc. 2: If your project is large enough that pure compile time is an issue, that might be a hint to split it into functionally separate sub-projects. Then you would rarely have to build the whole thing from scratch

Comment: @Alan I guess the advice given by WhiteFang34 has the best of both worlds - you can save the recompilation time if everything runs smoothly but you do have to clean/rebuild if you run into issues. I just got used to the convenience of starting the "all" target :)

Answer (score 2):

You can often avoid the clean step and javac will only compile changes. For rapid development you can probably get away with it and just run clean when you run into a problem. For builds that you'll deploy it's safest to always do a clean first to deal with any intricate dependencies that might not work otherwise.

That said, why in the world are you sharing source with a team through Dropbox? You should use [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) or [Git](http://git-scm.com/) (or plenty of others) for source control management. They're designed for this and you're going to want them as soon as you deal with anything potentially complex like branching and merging. Consider using [GitHub](https://github.com/) if you want to avoid setting much up.

Comment: Hehe, the reason for not using subversion is because the lab that hosts the code that we work on has not updated to the latest version of subversion; in the past they ran into problems with 1.6 clients confusing the 1.5 on the server, and breaking the repo.  We concluded that dropbox was "good enough" since it's a class project.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [javac commands documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) says :Only Java files that have no corresponding .class file or where the class file is older than the .java file will be compiled.

So there is no need to clean the resources every time.

Answer (score 0):

A clean is usually necessary to reduce the chances of errors due to renames and things may get left over.  However, I don't recommend doing it in Ant itself.

If you are using git, use the `exec` task to execute the command

```
git clean -fdx .
git reset --hard HEAD
```

From the root of your project file.  This will remove any files that are not part of source control and reset it to the top of the checked out state.

Otherwise I would do an `cmd /c rd /s` on Windows or `rm -rf` on UNIX on the build folders.